# Spring boot 2 client unable to parse header

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, http-headers, spring-boot-admin

I'm getting the below error while booting the client application in Spring Boot 2.

```
> 2018-08-24 12:26:15.689 DEBUG 19212 --- [nio-8001-exec-2]
> o.a.tomcat.util.net.SocketWrapperBase    : Socket:
> [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@67c796:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@a9face6:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected
> local=/ipaddress:8001 remote=/ipaddress:57886]], Read from buffer: [0]
> 2018-08-24 12:26:15.689 DEBUG 19212 --- [nio-8001-exec-2]
> o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request
> header
> 
> java.io.EOFException: null    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.fillReadBuffer(NioEndpoint.java:1259)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper.read(NioEndpoint.java:1193)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]    at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.fill(Http11InputBuffer.java:725)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]    at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:368)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]    at
> org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:687)
> ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]    at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
> [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]     at
> org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
> [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]     at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468)
> [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]     at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
> [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> [na:1.8.0_161]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> [na:1.8.0_161]    at
> org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
> [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]     at
> java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
```

Here is my client application.properties:

```
<!-- language: none -->

    server.port=8001 
    spring.boot.admin.client.url=localhost:9001 
    management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
    spring.boot.admin.client.username=admin
    spring.boot.admin.client.password=admin
    client.user.name=client 
    client.user.password=client 
    logging.file=relay-api.log
```

Here is my security config class

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.csrf().disable();
            http.headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity().disable();

            // All requests send to the Web Server request must be authenticated
            http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();

            // Use AuthenticationEntryPoint to authenticate user/password
            http.httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);


        }

        @Bean
        public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
            BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
            return bCryptPasswordEncoder;
        }


        @Value("${client.user.name}")
        private String username;

        @Value("${client.user.password}")
        private String password;

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {


            String encrytedPassword = this.passwordEncoder().encode(password);
            System.out.println("Encoded password " + encrytedPassword);


            InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer<AuthenticationManagerBuilder> //
            mngConfig = auth.inMemoryAuthentication();

            // Defines 2 users, stored in memory.
            // ** Spring BOOT >= 2.x (Spring Security 5.x)
            // Spring auto add ROLE_
            //UserDetails u1 = User.withUsername("relay-api").password(encrytedPassword).roles("USER").build();
            UserDetails u1 = User.withUsername(username).password(encrytedPassword).roles("USER").build();
           // UserDetails u2 = User.withUsername(admin).password(encrytedPassword).roles("USER").build();


            mngConfig.withUser(u1);
            //mngConfig.withUser(u2);


        }

    }
```

Here is the exact log which I can  see . it  is authentication issue but not able to understand what part I am missing

```
  2018-08-24 14:28:17.718 DEBUG 9960 --- [nio-8001-exec-5] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Socket: [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$NioSocketWrapper@5721a30a:org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioChannel@5dd9c87a:java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connected local=/ip:8001 remote=/ip:60359]], Status in: [OPEN_READ], State out: [CLOSED]
2018-08-24 14:28:17.719 DEBUG 9960 --- [io-8001-exec-13] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /actuator/mappings at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2018-08-24 14:28:17.719 DEBUG 9960 --- [io-8001-exec-13] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', GET]
2018-08-24 14:28:17.719 DEBUG 9960 --- [io-8001-exec-13] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'OPTIONS /actuator/mappings' doesn't match 'GET /logout
2018-08-24 14:28:17.719 DEBUG 9960 --- [io-8001-exec-13] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2018-08-24 14:28:17.719 DEBUG 9960 --- [io-8001-exec-13] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'OPTIONS /actuator/mappings' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2018-08-24 14:28:17.719 DEBUG 9960 --- [io-8001-exec-13] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT]
2018-08-24 14:28:17.720 DEBUG 9960 --- [io-8001-exec-13] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'OPTIONS /actuator/mappings' doesn't match 'PUT /logout
2018-08-24 14:28:17.720 DEBUG 9960 --- [io-8001-exec-13] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]
2018-08-24 14:28:17.720 DEBUG 9960 --- [io-8001-exec-13] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'OPTIONS /actuator/mappings' doesn't match 'DELETE /logout
2018-08-24 14:28:17.720 DEBUG 9960 --- [io-8001-exec-13] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : No matches found
2018-08-24 14:28:17.720 DEBUG 9960 --- [io-8001-exec-13] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /actuator/mappings at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'BasicAuthenticationFilter'
2018-08-24 14:28:17.720 DEBUG 9960 --- [io-8001-exec-13] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /actuator/mappings at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
2018-08-24 14:28:17.720 DEBUG 9960 --- [io-8001-exec-13] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /actuator/mappings at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
2018-08-24 14:28:17.720 DEBUG 9960 --- [io-8001-exec-13] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /actuator/mappings at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
2018-08-24 14:28:17.720 DEBUG 9960 --- [io-8001-exec-13] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@e325ed39: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffffa64e: RemoteIpAddress: 172.18.112.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
2018-08-24 14:28:17.720 DEBUG 9960 --- [io-8001-exec-13] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /actuator/mappings at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
2018-08-24 14:28:17.721 DEBUG 9960 --- [io-8001-exec-13] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /actuator/mappings at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2018-08-24 14:28:17.721 DEBUG 9960 --- [io-8001-exec-13] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /actuator/mappings at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2018-08-24 14:28:17.721 DEBUG 9960 --- [io-8001-exec-13] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /actuator/mappings; Attributes: [authenticated]
2018-08-24 14:28:17.721 DEBUG 9960 --- [io-8001-exec-13] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@e325ed39: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffffa64e: RemoteIpAddress: 172.18.112.1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
2018-08-24 14:28:17.721 DEBUG 9960 --- [io-8001-exec-13] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@49cb8ec1, returned: -1
2018-08-24 14:28:17.721 DEBUG 9960 --- [io-8001-exec-13] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=2018-08-24T08:58:17.721Z, principal=anonymousUser, type=AUTHORIZATION_FAILURE, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@ffffa64e: RemoteIpAddress: 172.18.112.1; SessionId: null, type=org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException, message=Access is denied}]
2018-08-24 14:28:17.722 DEBUG 9960 --- [io-8001-exec-13] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233) ~[spring-security-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:124) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:119) ~[spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:137) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:170) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:66) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1468) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.31.jar:8.5.31]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_161]
```

Here are the spring boot admin properties :

```
     server.port=9001
    #spring.jackson.date-format=com.slb.it.dataplatform.relay.RFC3339DateFormat
    #spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS=false

    ## Adding the credentials for spring boot admin login ui
    spring.security.user.name=admin
    spring.security.user.password=admin
```

Here is my admin security config class

```
       @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER)

      public static class SecuritySecureConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    /*      private final String adminContextPath;

            public SecuritySecureConfig(AdminServerProperties adminServerProperties) {
                this.adminContextPath = adminServerProperties.getContextPath();
            }*/

            @Override
            protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
                // @formatter:off
                SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler = new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
                successHandler.setTargetUrlParameter("redirectTo");
                successHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl( "/");

                http.headers().httpStrictTransportSecurity().disable();
                http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers( "/assets/**").permitAll() 
                    .antMatchers( "/login").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated() 
                    .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage( "/login").successHandler(successHandler).and() 
                .logout().logoutUrl( "/logout").and()
                .httpBasic().and() 
                .csrf()
                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())  
                    .ignoringAntMatchers(
                        "/instances",   
                        "/actuator/**"  
                    );
                // @formatter:on
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have a spring boot client application and one spring boot admin application 
So when ever I am starting the client application it tries to register itself to admin application for the actuator end points .
Here is my client application.properties :
server.port=8001
spring.boot.admin.client.url=http://localhost:9001
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
spring.boot.admin.client.username=vvvv
spring.boot.admin.client.password=vvvv
client.user.name=client
client.user.password=client
logging.file=relay-api.log

Comment: Have added the actual log .. Yes it is started but the admin console says that client is down .

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot 2 need SSL by default, you should set:

```
add 
server.ssl.enabled=false
in
application.properties
```